# Is it possible and good practice to create a global variable in Golang?

Tags: go

So I am creating a CLI application and some commands need an access to database.
Now all of them ended up having this code:

```
        db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open(fmt.Sprintf("%s/db/db.sqlite", dir)), &gorm.Config{})
        if err != nil {
            panic("failed to connect database")
        }
```

which kind of breaks the principle of DRY (dont repeat yourself).

Is there a way I can avoid this?

Comment: There is no global namespace in Go, but you can create globally-accessible variables by exporting them from any package (except `main`). So in that sense, of course it's possible. Whether it's a good idea or not is a matter of opinion. One popular opinion is to avoid globals whenever possible. But that's by far the only opinion on the matter.

Comment: Another common approach to your specific situation is dependency injection. Normally you'd connect to your database once, at the beginning of your application lifecycle, and pass the open connection into other parts of the app.

Comment: Does that mean that I would have to pass a huge amount of variables? Like DB connection, logger, API client, config, etc... ? Or if I bind all those to some struct, will that be an ok idea?

Comment: @Flimzy could you post your comments as answer, I will mark them as the answer to this question.

Comment: You can pass many variables. Or you can create an object that contains them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is roughly what @Flimzy had in mind when talking about dependency injection (tell me if I am wrong!)

[The entire self-contained example is here](https://play.golang.org/p/MXXq3bZ6rFz). The `Commands` struct has a pointer to the database in it. Any methods on the struct can have access to this opened database.

```golang
type Commands struct {
    db *gorm.DB
}

// An example command
func (c Commands) FindByUUID() (m []MyModel, err error) {
    // The commands now have access to the database
    c.db.Find(&m, "tag = ?", "foobar")
    return m, c.db.Error
}
```

Or pass it as an explicit parameter:

```golang
func FindByUUID(db *gorm.DB) (m []MyModel, err error) {
    db.Find(&m, "tag = ?", "foobar")
    return m, db.Error
}
```